# Contact between 3 nodes

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sprite-kit, nsarray

I am trying to detect whether or not there is contact between 3 nodes. My process to check this is as follows:

1. use `didBeginContact` to get the two names of nodes that just made contact.
2. Have an array that stores all names of nodes in contact with one another. Check if either the `firstBody.name` or  `secondBody.name` is already in the array
3. If either is, remove the `firstBody`, `secondBody` and whichever other node is node is in contact with them from their parent.

My code is as follows:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var arrayOfContacts: [AnyObject] = []

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
        contact.bodyA.node?.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        contact.bodyB.node?.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true

    switch(contactMask) {
    //at this point I am only looking to detect contact between 3 squares, hence the switch statement

    case CollisionCategoryBitmask.square | CollisionCategoryBitmask.square:

        var firstBody: SKNode!
        var secondBody: SKNode!

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA.node
            secondBody = contact.bodyB.node
        }
        else {
            firstBody = contact.bodyB.node
            secondBody = contact.bodyA.node
        }

        var individualContact: [Int] = []
        individualContact.append(firstBody.name!.toInt()!)
        individualContact.append(secondBody.name!.toInt()!)

        for subArray in arrayOfContacts {
            for name in subArray as! NSArray {
                if name as? Int == firstBody.name?.toInt() || name as? Int == secondBody.name?.toInt() {
                    println("this is connected to some others")
                    //this is where i would put in code to remove firstBody, secondBody and the other node from their parent

                }
                else {
                    println("not an already known contact, adding it to arrayOfContacts")
                    //this is where I would append individualContact to arrayOfContacts
                }
            }
        }
        default: break
    }}}
```

Every time there is a new contact, I first check if either of the contacting bodies is in the arrayOfContacts. If either is, I'll remove them from their parents, if neither is I'll add them to the array of contacts.

I have tried to give as good an impression of my code as possible. Although I have not included it, I also have the func `didEndContact` checking if two nodes that have separated are in the arrayOfContacts. If so, they are removed from the array.

Comment: There could well be some other process to check this that is much simpler...

Comment: Is this working, and you are just trying to find another, maybe simpler way, or there are some problems with this approach ?  Not sure if can help anything, but there is allContactBodies() method. It returns an array of SKPhysicsBody objects that current node's body is in contact with. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsBody/allContactedBodies

Comment: The problem is that the 'this is connected to some other' or 'not an already known contact...' is never printed.

Comment: I don't see where you're adding items to `arrayOfContacts`. If that array is empty, none of the statements in the `for subArray in arrayOfContacts` loop will execute.